# Filter JSON with desired keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects sample for example :

```
const data = [
    {
        Name: 'test_1',
        Value: '175',
        Description: 'desc_1'
    },
    {
        Name: 'test_2',
        Value: '175',
        Description: 'desc_2' 
    }
]
```

And an `env` file where I mark the data I want :

```
Name=true
Value=true
Description=false
```

How do I filter out the `data` file to only return the values of the keys `Name` and `Value`?

Desired output :

```
[
    {
        Name: 'test_1',
        Value: '175'
    },
    {
        Name: 'test_2',
        Value: '175',
    }
]
```

Comment: Please be aware that is not JSON data. (edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways in order to achieve the required output, here I'm making use of `Array.map` and `Array.reduce` methods.

```js
const data = [{ Name: 'test_1', Value: '175', Description: 'desc_1', }, {Name: 'test_2', Value: '176', Description: 'desc_2', }];

//In order to access from the env file
/*
const fields = {
  Name: process.env.Name,
  Value: process.env.Value,
  Description: process.env.Description
}
*/

//For the snippet purpose i'm using this hardcoded values
const fields = {
  Name: true,
  Value: true,
  Description: false
}

//Convert the object to an array of keys whose values are needed from the original data
const getConfigData = fields => Object.keys(fields).filter(key => fields[key])
let config = getConfigData(fields);

const getSelectedKeyValues = (data, config) => {
  return data.map(obj => config.reduce((acc, c) => (acc[c] = obj[c], acc), {}));
}

console.log("Name & Value:", getSelectedKeyValues(data, config));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```js
const data = [
  { Name: 'test_1', Value: '175', Description: 'desc_1' },
  { Name: 'test_2', Value: '175', Description: 'desc_2' }
]

let results = data.map((item) => {
  new_item = {};
  if (process.env.Name) new_item.Name = item.Name;
  if (process.env.Value) new_item.Value= item.Value;
  if (process.env.Description) new_item.Description= item.Description;
  return new_item;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your example is a JS array and no JSON string, you can use map:

`const result = data.map(d => { return {Name: d.name, Value: d.Value }});`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be filtering the objects `entries` when `mapping` and creating a new object from those `entries`.

```js
const data = [{
    Name: 'test_1',
    Value: '175',
    Description: 'desc_1'
  },
  {
    Name: 'test_2',
    Value: '175',
    Description: 'desc_2'
  }
]

const status = {
  Name: true,
  Value: true,
  Description: false
}

// props you want to keep
const keep = Object.keys(status).filter((k) => status[k]);

const result = data.map((d) => {
  // create object from entries based on what you want to keep
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(d).filter(([k]) => {
    return keep.includes(k)
  }));
})

console.log(result);
```